# Angularjs $http promise defer

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I am working with the `$http` in [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs)1.4.7.

I need to separate my controllers from any `$http` requests. So i created a service as follows:

```
app.service('MyService', function($http, $q, $rootScope) {

  this.getcustomers = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://call/to/rest/api'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      deferred.resolve(response.data);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };

});
```

Then in my controller i call that service as follows:

```
app.controller('registerationCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'MyService', '$location', function($scope, $http, MyService, $location) {
  $scope.custlst = [];

  $scope.getcustomers = function() {

    var x = MyService.getcustomers().then(function(data) {
      $scope.custlst = data;
    }, function(err) {
      alert(err);
    });

  }


}]);
```

Now, the above is not working it gives me a `ReferenceError` of error now defined and points to the `errorCallback` function in the service.

Question 1: What is wrong with the script?
Question 2: Is it important to use `$q`? Keeping in mind that the server can be slow.

Thanks.

Comment: `error` variable inside `errorCallback` is not defined, hence the error... You probably meant to do `function errorCallback(error) {...}` instead of `function errorCallback(response) {...}`. And no, you didn't need to use `$q` - you could have just returned the promise already generated by `$http`

Comment: Yup that fixed it thanks mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you don't need to use `$q` to create a promise. `$http` do it for you already, so you can simply do :

```
app.service('MyService', function($http) {
  this.getcustomers = function() {
    return $http.get({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://call/to/rest/api'
    });
  };
});
```

Then you can chain your `MyService.getcustomers` with `.then()` easily and handle the response like that :

```
MyService.getcustomers.then(
  function(data) {
    //do something with data
  },
  function(error) {
    //do something with error
  }
);
```

I think you should take a look at [this post](http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/) I you want to better understand how promises works and behaves.

**EDIT:** update deprecated call to `$http`.

Comment: Great so the service is good, but why is it recommended on the AngularJS site to use $q and defered if $http returns it. Might be stupid to ask but i cant get my head around it

Comment: note that `success` and `error` are deprecated in `$http` docs in favor of using promise `then`

Comment: yeah they have been deprecated. My bad, I'll update the code answer.

Comment: @user3052526 can you point to the article on the AngularJS site that recommended the use of `$q` with `$http`?  It sounds like an out of date page that probably can be updated or removed....

Comment: don't think you understood the deprecation part. Also can't chain `then` to `success`

Comment: Just remove the deprecated way...no point in showing that. Makes it confusing

Comment: Yeah I understand your point. I've removed it from the answer.

Comment: @Claies i sadly can not find it as i had been studying this issue for almost a week before posting here. I tested by making a wrong API call and $http indeed returns a promise

Comment: @Claies Yes i found it the link is on the AngularJS documentation [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http ) `The $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q service. While for simple usage patterns this doesn't matter much, for advanced usage it is important to familiarize yourself with these APIs and the guarantees they provide.`

Comment: @user3052526 well yes, the documentation definitely says that `$http` is based on `$q`, but it says you should familiarize yourself with how the API works, not use `$q` directly... Anyway, I think this answer shows you the right syntax to use.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the AngularJS docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

> **Deprecation Notice** The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

You don't need to use the $q promise.

As you're using GET request, you might use the shortcut method to perform GET request.: `$http.get();`.

So, you might try something like this:

**MyService service:** Only you need the `$http` service.

```
app.service("MyService", ["$http", function ($http) {
    this.getcustomers = function () {
        return $http.get("http://call/to/rest/api");
    };
}]);
```

The service above lets you use the service, in any controller. So, any controller can performs others action by using the same data.

**registerationCtrl controller:** You need the `$scope`, `MyService` and `location` services.

```
    app.controller("registerationCtrl", ["$scope", "MyService", "$location", function ($scope, MyService, location) {
        $scope.custlst = [];

        $scope.getcustomers = function () {
            MyService.getcustomers().then(function (response) {
                $scope.custlst = response.data;
            }, function (err) {
                alert(err);
            });
        };
    }]);
}]);
```

Comment: By using this way the service can be used in any controller.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comments, the error you're seeing is due to the `error` variable not being declared inside the `errorCallback` function.

As for `$q` - no need to use it, although the way you implemented would still work. To make it simpler and to follow the intent of promises (i.e. that they allow async code to mirror code composition of sync code) it's better to return the original promise of `$http` (or of `$http().then()`):

```
this.getcustomers = function() {
  return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://call/to/rest/api'
    })
    // pre-process the HTTP response and return the data
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    })
    // If needed, create a custom error to hide HTTP details from caller
    // otherwise, don't include .catch - the original error will "bubble up"
    .catch(function(error) {
      return $q.reject({
        msg: "something broke"
      });
    });
};
```

Then, the client can be used as you intended:

```
MyService.getcustomers()
  .then(function(data) {
    $scope.customers = data;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.msg);
  })
```